# Secure centralized HMAC-based authentication service

Tags: web-services, http, authentication, web, https

I need to centralize authentication to my rest web services and make this authentication the same for all of our webservices. So I started writing an external web service to take care about the authentication.

To keep compatibility, since the authentication was performed using a HMAC signature (signed using a private key) alongside the single request (so there is no token of any sort) I thought to make all web services to send the HMAC included inside the incoming request and the StringToSign (a representation of data used to generate the HMAC).

So the Authorization service can (knowing the private key) try to compose the same signature, if it matches then answers with `200 OK` and with a JSON object saying "authorized".

All this communication happens over HTTPS, but I'm trying to figure out what could happen if someone would intercept or modify this answer, making a `403 Forbidden` to become `200 OK`...

Should I use some sort of way to recognize this is the original answer? If so, what could I do?

I do agree that ssl certificates released by CA's are secure, but how could I make sure my HTTPS layer has not been compromised allowing an attacker to modify authorization responses?

P.S. please provide some standard solution if any, I don't want it to be related to the technology I'm using right now, since each service may use its own stack and I don't really want it to be .NET or something else because there's a proprietary implementation for the authentication mechanism.

Comment: How does the service pick the right secret to verify the HMAC? Does the request contain kind of a `From: user` field?

Comment: The Authorization header contains the public-key (id) of the client performing the operation, pretty much like Amazon S3 does, an example may be `Authorization: PUBLICKEY:SIGNATURE`. To specify what user you want to access the resource for I'm using the following URI `/user/:user_id/authorization`. This allows a client to access resources owned by another user, and also if actually I don't need it it's a good starting point IMO. So the service will know what's the secret according to the PUBLICKEY specified inside the Authorization header itself. If you have any suggestion please tell me.

Comment: Let's see if I understand: when Bob wants to see Alice's profile, its client requests `/user/alice/profile`. This service, in turn, authorizes Bob's request against `/user/alice/authorization`, sending an extra header like `Auth: BOB:profile`. Is this your current design?

Comment: TBH I've not already implemented the opportunity to request resources owned by another user (but one of the motivation I made it that way is to enable future support for that), so actually it's expecting the same user to be the one performing the authentication (picking the PRIVATE-KEY related to the one specified inside the URI itself). You raised a nice question I haven't tought about.

Comment: By performing a request to any resource such as `/user/alice/profile` the client will append an authorization header specifying who is it, for example: `Authorization: BOB:SIGNATURE`. The Profile service will then forward a request (before to perform any requested action) to the Authorization service, to the URI `/user/alice/authorization/` sending the signature and the stringToSign as GET params. Yeah, I'm missing a way to tell who is requesting the action... Maybe another GET param would be nice.

Comment: Or MAYBE I should perform a request against "/user/BOB/authorization" specifying the resource the client is requesting as a GET param.

Comment: Usually the authorization code is a *filter*: the incoming request is authorized **first**, and eventually dispatched. The more straightforward approach is: Bob requests `/alice/profile`, signing the message with his secret. The authorization code then either filters out the request, or forwards it to `/alice/profile`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20833/discussion-between-codeshining-and-raffaele)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All this communication happens over HTTPS, but I'm trying to figure
>   out what could happen if someone would intercept or modify this answer

This is what the *S* in HTTPS is for: SSL guarantees [integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail) of the message. If the attacker forges the request, the client will notice it.

You can ask the experts at [#security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, so I should not worry about stream manipulation, because the integrity is done at a lower (HTTP) level, am I right? If so that's nice and much simpler of what I was thinking about :-)

Since this webservices can also communicate over internet to send the HMAC+StringToSign to the Authorization service I was scared to miss something that could lead to security holes. BTW this already increases our security because with this design we have only 1 service knowing about user credentials.

Comment: Centralizing authentication and authorization improves *manageability* of your applications, not security, because if the secret is compromised, so are all of your applications. Also, doing authorization over the Internet will introduce latency and degrade user experience - but since I don't know the requirements, maybe it can't be done another way. Also, note that the authorization server is directly exposed to the Internet